# Prove that there are no integers $x,y$ such that $x^2+y^2=7,000,000$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove there are no integers $x,\,y$ such that $x^2+y^2=7,000,000$. (Hint: $\pmod7$)

I'm a little stuck on this problem. I'm assuming the hint is to arrange the problem as $x^2+y^2\equiv0\pmod7$, but I can't find anything that will let me proceed from there. I'm considering a proof by contradiction where I would assume there are such integers, come to a contradiction after a little hand waving and conclude that there are no such integers. I've been searching online and reading through my textbook but I can't seem to find anything useful.
If you know of any modulo theorems that would get me rolling here, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Hint : is $-1$ a square modulo $7$ ? Deduce that if $x^2+y^2 \equiv 0$ (mod $7$) then $x\equiv y\equiv 0$ (mod $7$).

Comment: An "academic" answer could be as follows: $7000000=7\cdot 2^6\cdot 5^6$ and the factor $7$ which is not congruent to 1 modulo 4 has an odd exponent. THIS IS AN ANSWER BECAUSE OF THE CHARACTERIZATION OF INTEGERS SUM OF TWO SQUARES.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list the squares mod 7 -- you just need to check what $0^2$, $1^2$, $2^2$, and $3^2$ are (since $4^2 \equiv (-3)^2 = 3^2$, etc.). Then you can check what combinations of them add up to $0$. Proceed from there.

Comment: So the way I'm interpreting this, x and y would both have to be some multiples of 7, otherwise their sum wouldn't be congruent to 0mod7, right?

Comment: @JakeRyan34 Exactly. Then from there you can try to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Okay, so if i say x is of the form x=7a, y of the form y=7b, x^2+y^2 becomes 49(a^2+b^2)=7,000,000. Then 7,000,000/49 = 142857.1429, which could not be formed from integers of the form a^2+b^2 so there is a contradiction. Sound about right?

Comment: @JakeRyan34 Sounds perfect.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: for $$x\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6\mod 7$$ we get $$x^2\equiv 0,1,2,4\mod 7$$

Answer (score 1):

Because you can show that if $x^2+y^2$ is divided by $7$ then $x$ an $y$ they are divided by $7$, which is impossible.